# Associating a value in map in clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, conditional-statements

I want to add a key-val pair in the output shown below,where it is numbered 2 and site-label is co2.

```
{:correct? false,
 :training-countdown nil,
 :site-communication {0 [], 1 [], 2 [], 3 (0 1), 4 (3 2)},
 :site-label :t-<<:temperature-:humidity_i3>-:co2_i4>,
 :agreement 478/739,
 :breakdown
 {0
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :temperature,
   :agreement 1,
   :site-order 0,
   :transformed-confidence 0.6367035786260278,
   :confidence-ma 0.86235090749618,
   :raw-votes (0.17910252984637456 0.10219403555517105),
   :id 10001,
   :class 0,
   :raw-confidence 0.17910252984637456,
   :site-type :p-site,
   :quantile 139/1000,
   :confidence 0.6367035786260278,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 14500}},
  1
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :humidity,
   :agreement 1,
   :site-order 0,
   :transformed-confidence 0.7396347578595606,
   :confidence-ma 0.7673990631272951,
   :raw-votes (0.05875164784557538 0.020681676807254086),
   :id 10001,
   :class 0,
   :raw-confidence 0.05875164784557538,
   :site-type :p-site,
   :quantile 273/1000,
   :confidence 0.7396347578595606,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 26600}},
  2
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :co2,
   :agreement 1,
   :site-order 0,
   :transformed-confidence 0.6885013017580619,
   :confidence-ma 0.8687745984384241,
   :raw-votes (6.209281474901374E-4 2.809265707284352E-4),
   :id 10001,
   :class 0,
   :raw-confidence 6.209281474901374E-4,
   :site-type :p-site,
   :quantile 79/1000,
   :confidence 0.6885013017580619,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 14400}},
  3
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :t-<:temperature-:humidity_i3>,
   :agreement 498/499,
   :site-order 1,
   :transformed-confidence 0.7146049092604565,
   :confidence-ma 0.9331555208607589,
   :raw-votes (220.42790579127143 551.9326320865079),
   :id 10001,
   :class 1,
   :raw-confidence 551.9326320865079,
   :site-type :t-site,
   :quantile 9/100,
   :confidence 0.7146049092604565,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 241300}},
  4
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :t-<<:temperature-:humidity_i3>-:co2_i4>,
   :agreement 478/739,
   :site-order 2,
   :transformed-confidence 0.932189769224312,
   :confidence-ma 0.845843308389129,
   :raw-votes (51.39818941403593 706.5728250787176),
   :id 10001,
   :class 1,
   :raw-confidence 706.5728250787176,
   :site-type :t-site,
   :quantile 317/500,
   :confidence 0.932189769224312,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 283700}}},
 :site-order 2,
 :transformed-confidence 0.932189769224312,
 :confidence-ma 0.845843308389129,
 :raw-votes (51.39818941403593 706.5728250787176),
 :id 10001,
 :class 1,
 :raw-confidence 706.5728250787176,
 :truth 0,
 :site-type :t-site,
 :quantile 317/500,
 :candidate-results
 {-1
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :humidity,
   :agreement 1,
   :site-order 0,
   :transformed-confidence 0.7396347578595606,
   :confidence-ma 0.7673990631272951,
   :raw-votes (0.05875164784557538 0.020681676807254086),
   :id 10001,
   :class 0,
   :raw-confidence 0.05875164784557538,
   :site-type :p-site,
   :quantile 273/1000,
   :confidence 0.7396347578595606,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 26600}},
  3
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :t-<:temperature-:humidity_i3>,
   :agreement 498/499,
   :site-order 1,
   :transformed-confidence 0.7146049092604565,
   :confidence-ma 0.9331555208607589,
   :raw-votes (220.42790579127143 551.9326320865079),
   :id 10001,
   :class 1,
   :raw-confidence 551.9326320865079,
   :site-type :t-site,
   :quantile 9/100,
   :confidence 0.7146049092604565,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 241300}},
  4
  {:training-countdown nil,
   :site-label :t-<<:temperature-:humidity_i3>-:co2_i4>,
   :agreement 478/739,
   :site-order 2,
   :transformed-confidence 0.932189769224312,
   :confidence-ma 0.845843308389129,
   :raw-votes (51.39818941403593 706.5728250787176),
   :id 10001,
   :class 1,
   :raw-confidence 706.5728250787176,
   :site-type :t-site,
   :quantile 317/500,
   :confidence 0.932189769224312,
   :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 283700}}},
 :confidence 0.932189769224312,
 :process-time {:cpu-nano 0, :wall-nano 283700}}
```

Comment: Could you simplify your post to be minimal input and minimal desired output?

Comment: I want to add a new key value pair in subset of map which satisfies some condition.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed so we can improve on it.

Comment: I tried this-- but it gives me only the filtered result.
 (let [result (->> result
  (filter #(= (nth % 0) :breakdown))
         (map #(get (nth % 1) 2))
       (map #(assoc % :cond-prob 4)) 
                                                 
)
  ]

Answer (score 3):

The function that you are looking for is [assoc-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in), that takes a map, a series of keys to traverse the nested map and the value that needs to be put at the end of the path formed by the keys.

Example:

```
user=> (def measures0 {:items {0 {:label "original label" :comment "nice"} 1 {:label "label 1" :comment "nice 1"}}})
#'user/measures0

user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint measures0)
{:items
 {0 {:label "original label", :comment "nice"},
  1 {:label "label 1", :comment "nice 1"}}}
nil

user=> (def measures-updated (assoc-in measures0 [:items 0 :label] "UPDATED LABEL"))
#'user/measures-updated

user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint measures-updated)
{:items
 {0 {:label "UPDATED LABEL", :comment "nice"},
  1 {:label "label 1", :comment "nice 1"}}}
```